# How Can I Convert TextBox Input to a Double and Return a Vaue?

Tags: c#, webforms

I want to get the input of values of the width textbox, height textbox, and length textbox. I have it set so it page_loads when input is changed. I want to use the inputs of width, height, and length to calculate volume with the input parameters and then output the result back into the label.

I've been trying to get `double.TryParse()` and `convert.ToDouble()` to work.

```
        double volume;
        double width = 0;
        double height = 0;
        double length = 0;

        //get input from text boxes here 
        ???

        calculateVolume(width, height, length, out volume);

        label.Text = String.Format("Volume: {0}", volume);
    }

    public static void calculateVolume(double width, double height, double length, out double volume)
    {
        volume = (width * height * length);
    }
```

Comment: Please update the question to show the actual code that you used when trying to use the `TryParse` methods.  Are there any error messages?  If so, post their detail.

Comment: I assume you need to calculate width of the textbox to show it on page load so that the text inside is fully visible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use try parse.

double.TryParse(Width.Text, out width);

Just make sure it's on its own line as the out keyword is there to place the output into that variable. The return of the function is a Boolean value to indicate if it was able to be parsed.

Comment: Could you please give me an example, I am trying to learn C# and a clear example on my scenario would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide textbox with a valid keyPress event given below, This will allow restricting the user to provide  a valid "double" value in "String" format that we can parse later to "double"

```
 private void All_textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.'))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // only allow one decimal point
        if ((e.KeyChar == '.'))
        {
            var senderText = (sender as TextBox);
            // check if it's in the beginning of text not accept and check if there is already exist a '.'
            if (senderText != null && (senderText.TextLength == 0 || senderText.SelectionStart == 0 || (senderText.Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can use either

> Convert.ToDouble(Height.Text);
>   double.TryParse(Height.Text, out Height);